# How should I go about creating a Cocoa application that outputs to the command-line?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm attempting to build a cocoa application that uses a third-party cocoa API (it also needs to respond to a URL-scheme). I want my application to be as simple as possible, and act as a "helper" application for something else.

It seems that the best way for me to do this is to have the application launched from the command-line [with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146849/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-objective-c) and then write some output, either directly to the CLI or to some intermediary file such as a plist, before exiting.

How can I best produce the output (assuming I just dump it to the command line), and/or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Are you asking to redirect NSLog to file?

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "format %d string\n", 1337);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General advice only, "best" is subjective!

If you will be producing multiple "blobs" (that's a technical term ;-)) of output use C's standard I/O functions, if you are just going to output one blob you can use `write`. The basic approach is:

1. Produce your output as an `NSString` - anyway you like
2. Use the `UTF8String` method of `NSString` (or convert to some other character set encoding) to produce a C string
3. Output the C string to `stdout` with `fputs` etc. or to file descriptor `1` using `write`

If you are doing this multiple times wrap the above up as a method which takes a format string/arguments as needed etc.

You'll see some CLI applications produce output to the terminal in plist format, this can be useful for applications which are to be helpers - the calling application can read the output via a pipe and convert the plist to a dictionary/array just like reading a .plist file. It is a more direct approach than writing the plist to a file and then reading it back.

But helpers don't need to have a CLI or a GUI, you can launch and communicate with them with various forms of IPC. If your app will be sandboxed XPC helpers should be considered.

HTH